# Call docker command line to remove all containers from python

Tags: python

I am trying to port:

https://coderwall.com/p/ewk0mq/stop-remove-all-docker-containers

to a python script. So far I have:

```
def remove_all_containers():
    subprocess.call(['docker', 'stop','$(docker ps -a -q)'])
    subprocess.call(['docker', 'rm','$(docker ps -a -q)'])  
    return;
```

But get:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: $(docker ps -a -q)
```

I have also tried:

```
def remove_all_containers():
    subprocess.call(['docker', 'stop',$(docker ps -a -q)])
    subprocess.call(['docker', 'rm',$(docker ps -a -q)])
    return;
```

But that gives:

```
    subprocess.call(['docker', 'stop',$(docker ps -a -q)])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

it seems I need to nest another subprocess call into the parent subprocess call. Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You're using $(shell features), and you're not calling through the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Command substitution `$(...)` is a shell feature, therefore you must run your commands on a shell:

```
subprocess.call('docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)', shell=True)
subprocess.call('docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)', shell=True)
```

---

**Additional improvements:**

It's not required, but I would suggest using [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) (or `run(..., check=True)`, see below) instead of [`call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), so that if an error occurs it doesn't go unnoticed:

```
subprocess.check_call('docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)', shell=True)
subprocess.check_call('docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)', shell=True)
```

You can also go another route: parse the output of `docker ps -a -q` and then pass to `stop` and `rm`:

```
container_ids = subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'ps', '-aq'], encoding='ascii')
container_ids = container_ids.strip().split()
if container_ids:
    subprocess.check_call(['docker', 'stop'] + container_ids])
    subprocess.check_call(['docker', 'rm'] + container_ids])
```

If you're using Python 3.5+, you can also use the newer [`run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function:

```
# With shell
subprocess.run('docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)', shell=True, check=True)
subprocess.run('docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)', shell=True, check=True)

# Without shell
proc = subprocess.run(['docker', 'ps', '-aq'], check=True, stdout=PIPE, encoding='ascii')
container_ids = proc.stdout.strip().split()
if container_ids:
    subprocess.run(['docker', 'stop'] + container_ids], check=True)
    subprocess.run(['docker', 'rm'] + container_ids], check=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nice official library for python, that helps with Docker.
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

```
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient(Config.DOCKER_BASE_URL) 
docker_containers = client.containers.list(all=True)
for dc in docker_containers:
   dc.remove(force=True)
```

We've received all containers and remove them all doesn't matter container status is 'started' or not.
The library could be useful if you can import it into code.